# How to solve Failure Build Flutter debug App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to debug the app on my phone but I got those errors on visual studio code

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
      > Failed to transform arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
         > Could not download arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed)
            > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed.jar'.
               > Tag mismatch!
```

my build.gradle file is:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
```

so how do we solve this issue? because I got that error many times in different situations
I really appreciate any help you can provide.